# Align through two different strings of different lengths?

Tags: python, string, loops

If I have two strings like:

```
plaintext = "hello"
key = "hi"
```

How do I align the letters (or other characters like spaces and punctuation) together without going out of range? So far I'm doing this but I keep running into the string out of index error.

```
encryption = ""
for index in range(len(plaintext)):
    if plaintext[index] in alphabet:
        encryption += vigenere_encrypt(plaintext[index], key[index])
    if plaintext[index] not in alphabet:
        encryption += plaintext[index]
return encryption
```

I'm essentially trying to make my key match up with the length of plaintext so `"hi" --> "hihih"` 
which is the same length as "hello" so it can loop through both at the same time without running into the out of range error

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the expected output for these two strings?

Comment: why are you indexing at all and what is vigenere_encrypt?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to make my key match up with the length of plaintext so "hi" should become "hihih" which is the same length as "hello"

Comment: I have a feeling str.translate will do a lot of what you code is doing

Answer (score 1):

If you want your shorter `key` string to wrap around, use a modulus when indexing it:

```
encryption += vigenere_encrypt(plaintext[index], key[index % len(key)])
```

Another approach is to use `itertools.cycle` to make an iterator that repeats the values from `key` forever as you iterate over it. You can then combine this with `plaintext` using `zip` (a more Pythonic way of combining two sequences than using indexes). Here's a version that does the whole encryption in a generator expression:

```
import itertools

encryption = "".join(vigenere_encrypt(plain_char, key_char)
                         if plain_char in alphabet else plain_char
                     for plain_char, key_char in zip(plaintext, itertools.cycle(key))
```

Comment: A generator expression with join is actually slower and not any more space efficient as you will end up with a list regardless

Comment: I meant that `str.join` may be more efficient than repeated use of `+=` on strings, which (in a naive implementation) would user `O(N**2)` time due to the repeated copying of the early characters. Because it's such a common thing for beginners to extend strings with `+=`, CPython has some special checks in `str.__add__` that will actually reuse the left hand argument without copying it if there are no other references, but I think it's a bad idea to rely upon that optimization.